# I'm creating an android app which saves user's file like pdf, music, word files, pics, videos, etc

Tags: java, android

When the user selects an option he'll be directed to a new activity which will contain a Floating action button which will help him to add a folder. How do I create a new folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a folder in the device, you can use this method:

```
public void createFfolder(String folderPath){
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
}
```

in case the folder doesn't exists, it creates it.

Just make sure you have the *WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE* permission in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

hope it helps

Comment: in the activity where you have the Floating Action Button. Put this code on the click listener of the button.

Comment: how to take the name of the new folder from the user and use it to create a new folder?